# Why is the version of python not appearing after entering the command in cmd?

Tags: python, command-prompt

I have entered "python --version" in my command prompt after installing python but the version is still not appearing, why is that so?[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3IWl.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python? Or could there be a `python.cmd` or something similar that is in the path *before* the real one. What does `where python` give you? What about `python -c "print(0)"`?

Comment: Oh yes, there are some paths before the python paths where all the python.exe and scripts folder exist, I have moved them forward and it works now, thank you so much